# No option to up TX-Power in Kali Linux

Tags: wifi, kali-linux

I want to make my TX-Power but I don't have the option. When I type `iwconfig` i get this:

```
wlan0     802.11b/g  link  ESSID:"296033"  
       Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.437 GHz  Access Point: 7C:05:07:29:60:33   
       Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   
       Retry min limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
       Encryption key:off
       Power Management:off
       Link Quality=90/100  Signal level=-32 dBm  Noise level=-114 dBm
       Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
       Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0`
```

I don't see an option for TX, how do I make my Wi-Fi card stronger?

Answer (score 1):

You can use iw to register your hardware to a country. Some hardware cannot be changed.

install wavemon to monitor strength of signal (not needed for change).

```
apt-get install wavemon
```

For example, to set it to the US you would 
bring lan down

```
iwconfig wlan0
```

register to US or BO with 1000mwats of power

```
iw reg set US

iw reg set BO
```

or change directly

```
iwconfig wlan0 txpower 30
```

by law you need to OBEY the FCC laws regulating your region.

Comment: Do I need wavemon to up tx power?

Comment: thanks @kprovost7314, wavemon is monitoring software to visually see the transmission signal strength. You do not need to install wavemon to change the tx power.

Comment: Well with or without wavemon it wont work. Whenever I try iw reg set BO, it gives me nl80211 not found.